# Puting attributes to the <html> root-element with xslt 2.0

Tags: html, xslt, lang, xsl-stylesheet

Is it possible to put a `xml:lang` or `lang` attribute to the html root-element `<html>` using xslt 2.0?

The problem is, that the only allowed attributes for `xsl:stylesheet` are: `id`, `exclude-result-prefixes`, `extension-element-prefixes`, `version` and of course `xmlns`. Other attributes are being ignored by any xslt-processor.

There must be a way to extend the element `<html>` I hope?

Thanks a lot.

Code (xhtml in this case):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
   xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:tst="http://www.ma-buwi-fh.de"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xml:lang="de">

<xsl:output method="xhtml"
   encoding="UTF-8"
   indent="yes"
   doctype-public='-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN'
   doctype-system='http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd'
    />
```

The result looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:tst="http://www.ma-buwi-fh.de"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: You should not edit your question after learning that your assumptions were wrong. That makes it hard to follow the reasoning in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaking the `stylesheet` element (the root element of an XSLT stylesheet) for `html` (the root element of an HTML document).

The attributes you cite are the ones allowed for the `stylesheet` element. See the relevant part of the specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#stylesheet-element).

So, specify the `lang` attribute on the `html` element you output, not on the `stylesheet` element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html lang="EN">
      <!--HTML content-->
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want anyone to diagnose your actual problem, you must needs show your XSLT code.